# Facebook API: Get all profile pictures

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

What is the best way to get ALL profile pictures from a given user? What permissions do I need?

I know I can access the main profile pic using `https://graph.facebook.com/[uid]/picture`, but how do I get the entire album?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

> how do I get the entire album?

You need `https://graph.facebook.com/[uid]/albums?access_token=[AUTH_TOKEN]` to get JSON array of all the albums of a user.

You will get three important things from here `id` - album id, `name` - album name, and `type` - album type.

> What permissions do I need?

The permission required is `user_photos` [see here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)

> What is the best way to get ALL profile pictures from a given user?

Profile Pictures are under "Profile Pictures" album. To get to profile album, you need to look into albums array (as mentioned previously), iterate through the JSON result-set, until you get an album with name = `Profile Pictures` and type = `profile`. Get `id` of this object. This is *the* profile pictures album.

Now you can access it similar to you access any other album. That is, `https://graph.facebook.com/[ALBUM_ID]/photos?access_token=[AUTH_TOKEN]` this will list all the profile pictures of the user ever uploaded.

Hope this helps.

refer: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: Is it possible for them to change the name of the profile pictures album? Is it reliable to trust the name of the album?

Comment: rely on `type`. name is not editable for `profile pictures` album AFAIK.

Comment: @Nishant, if there are a lot of profile pictures (i.e., 100 photos) how would you get ALL of them using the `https://graph.facebook.com/[ALBUM_ID]/photos?access_token=[AUTH_TOKEN]`? Because it currently stops after the 25th photo

Comment: $A = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=".$facebook->getAccessToken();
                var_dump($A); exit; // It did not work! :(

Comment: is it possible to order the pictures by date of setting them as profile picture? I want the last 5 profile pictures..

Comment: Is it possible to get album of friend ?

Comment: seems like its working with graph api version 2.2. any idea how it works about graph api 2.8?

Comment: Please also add &locale=en_US to the end of that URL, since the FB API otherwise returns the string "Profile Pictures" in the users own locale. Which is crazy btw :)

Answer (score 9):

You can pass the "limit=0" to avoid paging altogether, and you get all the photos in one call.

Answer (score 5):

To get all profile pictures, firstly you need to get list of all albums, but if count of albums more than 24 you will not get the rest and you probably will not get profile photos album. For this you need to pass `limit=0` to get albums URL.

Here is example code:

```
$tokenUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=$yourAppId&redirect_uri=$yourRedirectUrl 
                &client_secret=$yourAppSecret&code={$_GET["code"]}";

$accessToken = file_get_contents($tokenUrl);

$extAlbumUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?$accessToken&limit=0";

$albums = json_decode(file_get_contents($extAlbumUrl));
```

Answer (score 2):

We will not get directly all profile pictures first we need fetch all albums using below URL

[https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/
472802896428726/albums?access_token={access_token}&fields=id,name,cover_photo,count,from,type](https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/%20472802896428726/albums?access_token=%7Baccess_token%7D&fields=id,name,cover_photo,count,from,type)

Filter array using condition  where **type = profile and name = Profile Pictures** 
then use album id to get photos using below URL

[https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/
124683854573967/photos?access_token={access_token}&fields=id,source](https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/%20124683854573967/photos?access_token=%7Baccess_token%7D&fields=id,source)

Answer (score 1):

There is some way to get the albums of public users without any relation. For example, I'm not friend of the user "foo" but I want his photos. I can see his photos in the UI of Facebook but I can not get through the graph.

I'm using explorer from facebook with all permissions and I'm getting always an empty JSON.
There is some way to get the photos that I'm seeing in the UI? These photos are public.

Real example:

UI from facebook:
https://www.facebook.com/sonia.milan.9/photos You can see all his photos.

Using graph API: 
sonia.milan.9/albums
Return:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

Comment: Getting Sorry, this content isn't available right now at the link

Answer (score 0):

You use paging and offset to get next 5 or change the limit to whatever.