# Get Facebook only Profile Photos using GraphAPI

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created an Android Application in that I want to get only profile photos of Facebook user.

I tried using Graph API but it gives all the albums. There is any way to find only Profile Photos of user?

I tried below command in Graph API:

> me/?fields=photos{album}

Thanks.

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/UID/picture?height=200&width=200 , UID = the profile Id

Comment: @Janak I need all photos, not single

Comment: @saragZala     Update Your Question, You Mention this "I want to get only profile photos of Facebook user."

Comment: I already mentioned "Photos" not "Photo". Please check.

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5058559/3867515

Comment: _“There is any way to find only Profile Photos of user?”_ – get the photos from the profile pictures album …?

Comment: @CBroe, How to get it?

Comment: Get the list of the user’s albums, and look for the one with the right name. And then use the id of that album, to get the photos in it.

Comment: @CBroe, Ok I will try.

Comment: @CBroe, Thanks I got the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution by below code:

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    String id;
                    try {
                        final JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONObject("albums").getJSONArray("data");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name").equals("Profile Pictures")) {
                                id = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"); // ID of Profile Pictures Album

                                new GraphRequest(
                                        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                                        "/" + id + "?fields=photos.limit(6){picture}",
                                        null,
                                        HttpMethod.GET,
                                        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                                            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                                                try {
                                                    JSONObject jsonMain = response.getJSONObject();
                                                    JSONObject jsonGraphObj = jsonMain.getJSONObject("graphObject");
                                                    if (jsonGraphObj.has("photos")) {
                                                        if (jsonGraphObj.getJSONObject("photos").has("data")) {
                                                            JSONArray jsonArrayData = jsonGraphObj.getJSONObject("photos").getJSONArray("data");
                                                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                                                if (i != 0) {
                                                                    String url = jsonArrayData.getJSONObject(i).getString("picture");
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                ).executeAsync();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        DialogsUtils.removeProgressDialog();
                    }
                }
            });

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "albums");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
```